# Parse XML info within a parent tag

Tags: jquery, html, xml

I got an XML that looked like this:

```
<state1>
<county>
<villager>John Smith</villager>
<income>3000</income>
</county>
<county>
<villager>John Smith</villager>
<income>3500</income>
</county>
<county>
<villager>Peter Smith</villager>
<income>3100</income>
</county>
<county>
<villager>Paul Smith</villager>
<income>3200</income>
</county>
</state1>

<state2>
. .
</state2>
```

I use these codes to parse the info now to HTML table:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "election2008.xml", 
  dataType: "xml",
  success: function(xml) {
   $(xml).find('county').each(function(){   
    var Col0 = $(this).find('villager').text();
    var Col1 = $(this).find('income').text();
    $('<tr></tr>').html('<td>'+Col0+'</td><td>'+Col1+'</td>').appendTo('#chart');
   });
  }
 });
});
</script>
```

I wanted to only retrieve data inside State1 and output them to HTML. How do i do that?

Currently my script parse ALL the info and put them together inside one big HTML table, but I wanted to only read state1 data. is it possible? thanks

Comment: You'll have to be more clear.  Are you wanting to create `files` that contain the `xml output` from those?

Comment: Sorry I wanted to output them to HTML, and I did, just that the HTML table is very huge because it contains the WHOLE xml file data. I just wanted to take one state per html. I'll edit now thanks for reminding.

Comment: How do you know which HTML file you're inside of? Are you meaning you want to separate each county into it's own table within the same file? or you want to check the name of the file, and depending on that file, retrieve a certain state?

Comment: I think i dont need so complicated, I can do it manually per html file. I just wanted jQuery to ONLY get data inside state1, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand correctly - you want to create new HTML files with the 1 state in each.

You can use PHP to create the html file, look here: http://www.tizag.com/phpT/filewrite.php

Then, while you're parsing your XML in the AJAX function, send the state data to the PHP file to write you a new page containing the table.

EDIT:

Ohhh do you mean something like:

```
success: function(xml) {
    var stat1 = $(xml).find('state1');  
    $(stat1).find('county').each(function(){    
        var Col0 = $(stat1).find('villager').text();
        var Col1 = $(stat1).find('income').text();
        $('<tr></tr>').html('<td>'+Col0+'</td><td>'+Col1+'</td><td>'+Col2+'</td>').appendTo('#chart');
    });
```

Comment: I could add manually the html files. Just that I want each html file to retrieve only the one state at a time. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing you care about is capturing state1, then we can checking the index of the array like so:

```
success: function(xml) {
    $(xml).find('county').each(function(i){ <--- **i** is the index
        if( i == 0 ){ //<--- if index is zero, which is state 1
            var Col0 = $(this).find('villager').text();
            var Col1 = $(this).find('income').text();
            $('<tr></tr>').html('<td>'+Col0+'</td><td>'+Col1+'</td><td>'+Col2+'</td>').appendTo('#chart');
        }
    });
  }
```

alternatively, you could simply request the first by simply doing

```
var state1 = $(xml).find('state1').find('county').eq(0),
    Col0 = state1.find('villager').text(),
    Col1 = state1.find('income').text(),
    Con2 = state1.find('something').text();
```

so on and so forth.

If you want to get the item based on the filename requesting it, you can use this method:

```
//get the url pathname
var url = window.location.pathname;

//split the pathname on the last occurence of a `/`, which should be superceded by state1.html or state2.html, etc..
var state = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/'));

Now let's get the county that we want....
var countyNum = state.match(/[0-9]/)[0];

//and now the corresponding county within the state...

var county = $(xml).find('state').eq(0).find('county').eq(countyNum);
```

Comment: the first method return nothing. second one not sure how to use it... can u elaborate? thank you